# Deriving limits when n goes to infinity

Tags: calculus

How do i evaluate the limit below?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1-x^{n+1}}=\left\{\begin{array}\\
&\text{if}&|x|<1\\
&\text{if}&|x|>1
\end{array}\right.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1-x^{n+1}}$$

Let's do the first part, if $|x|<1$. Let's say it's $0.5$ (positive or negative won't matter at the infinity scale):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1-0.5^{n+1}}$$

Focus on $0.5^{n+1}$:

$$0.5^{n+1}=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$$

And of course, as $n$ approaches $\infty$:

$$\frac{1}{2^{\infty+1}}=0$$

{The denominator will get so large, it will just be 0.}

Now plug this result back in!

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1-0.5^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{1-0}=1$$

Alright, now time to do it for $|x| > 1$. Take $x=5$ for example:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1-5^{n+1}}$$

Look at the bottom again. We know that:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \pm5^{n+1}=\pm\infty$$

{Positive or negative won't really matter here either.}

Plugging it in back, we see:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1-5^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{1\mp\infty}$$

Again, always look at the denominator. $1\mp\infty$ will be either positive or negative $\infty$. Since there is $\infty$ the denominator, this will yield to $0$.

If you have any questions or need further explanations, comment below~.

Cheers!
-Shahar

Comment: thanks alot for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:  1, if /x/ < 1 and 0 if /x/ > 1. And this follows from the fact that:

/x/^n --> 0 when /x/ < 1 and --> infinity if /x/ > 1 as n --> infinity.

Comment: what are the steps to evaluate it? i rather confused when i meet questions with the modulus

Comment: @user136934: I just explained in my edited answer.

Comment: sorry but i don't really understand the |x|<1 part.

Comment: @user136934: for that one, the easiest way is to try out an example : 0.7^n, let n is very large and calculate 0.7^45 to see what shows up on your TI-83 display screen ?

Comment: thanks alot for the explanation